# When send and receive in Outlook 2010 reported error (0x8004010F)

Tags: email, windows-10, outlook-2010

I am using Windows 10 and Outlook 2010. With the same profile configurations send and receive operation worked before, but suddenly it's getting following error.

```
Task 'bandara@domain.lk - Sending' 
reported error (0x8004010F) : 'Outlook data file cannot be accessed.'

Task 'bandara@domain.lk - Receiving' 
reported error (0x8004010F) : 'Outlook data file cannot be accessed.'
```

Comment: Can provide a data file location?

Comment: It's in my D drive and have all permission. @ErandaPeiris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens due to change in the location of PST file on the machine.

1. Move your data file to C drive (default location).
2. Then make that data file set as default.

I think it will work.

Comment: That works for me, but it should be work in other drives as well.